# How to use a button (dropdown) text as a variable in Python with Kivy?

Tags: python, variables, button, kivy, dropdown

I am building several dropdown with Kivy to obtain a date :

dropdown day, dropdown month, etc...

But for the dropdown day I need to know the year and the month to calculate the number of days.

So I would like to use the value of the "year dropdown" and "month dropdown" to calculate the number of days. For example for November of 2019 I would have a 30 buttons dropdown.

The issues are :

- To run the program Python wants an initial value for the month and year, but at the begining the button's value is a string : "Année" which means year in french, and similarly for the month button.
- If I give python a random value for month and year it will run but when I select another month of year in the GUI, the number of days is not updating.

-->It seems that the buttons values can't be linked using

```
int(button.text)
```

Here are the main parts of my program. 
I wrote my 5 dropdowns as follow (this one is for years from 2019 to 2020) :

```
dropdown2=DropDown()
        for y in range(today.year,today.year+2):
            btn = Button(text='%d' %y,size_hint_y=None,height=44)
            btn.bind(on_release=lambda btn:dropdown2.select(btn.text))
            dropdown2.add_widget(btn)

        yearbutton = Button(text='Année', size_hint=(None, None))
        yearbutton.bind(on_release=dropdown2.open)

        dropdown2.bind(on_select=lambda instance,value2: setattr(yearbutton, 'text',value2))
```

Then I want to use yearbutton.text to defin daybutton as follow :

```
dropdown3=DropDown()
        for d in range(1,calendar.monthrange(int(yearbutton.text),int(monthbutton.text))[1]+1):
            btn=Button(text='%d' %d,size_hint_y=None,height=44)
            btn.bind(on_release=lambda btn: dropdown3.select(btn.text))
            dropdown3.add_widget(btn)


        daybutton=Button(text='Jour',size_hint=(None,None))
        daybutton.bind(on_release=dropdown3.open)

        dropdown3.bind(on_select=lambda instance,value3:setattr(daybutton,'text',value3))
```

And of course this error occurs in the "for" row :

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'Année'
```

because the inital value of my "yearbutton" is a string.

reprex :

```
import calendar
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.dropdown import DropDown
from kivy.app import App


class Design(GridLayout):
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super(Design,self). __init__(**kwargs)
        self.cols=1 #cols du widget button

        self.inside = GridLayout() #creation d'un widget-layout
        self.inside.cols=4

        dropdown1=DropDown()
        for month in range (1,13):
            btn = Button(text='%d' % month, size_hint_y=None, height=44)
            btn.bind(on_release=lambda btn: dropdown1.select(btn.text))
            dropdown1.add_widget(btn)

        monthbutton = Button(text='Mois', size_hint=(None, None))
        monthbutton.bind(on_release=dropdown1.open)

        dropdown1.bind(on_select=lambda instance, value1: setattr(monthbutton, 'text', value1))

        dropdown3=DropDown()
        for d in range(1,calendar.monthrange(2019,int(monthbutton.text))[1]+1):
            btn=Button(text='%d' %d,size_hint_y=None,height=44)
            btn.bind(on_release=lambda btn: dropdown3.select(btn.text))
            dropdown3.add_widget(btn)


        daybutton=Button(text='Jour',size_hint=(None,None))
        daybutton.bind(on_release=dropdown3.open)

        dropdown3.bind(on_select=lambda instance,value3:setattr(daybutton,'text',value3))

        self.inside.add_widget(daybutton)
        self.inside.add_widget(monthbutton)

        self.add_widget(self.inside)

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Design()

if __name__=="__main__":
    MyApp().run()
```

Comment: provide a [mre]

Comment: I added it in the question :)

Answer (score 0):

Finally using Kivy Calendar, easier !